# Changing the colour of a specific list item in HTML5/CSS

Tags: css, html, colors, background

I'm trying to change the background colour of the items in a list without selecting the entire list. I want the background of the items in the first list to be green and the second list to be teal, but not have the bullet points themselves with a green background?

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Exercises 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exercise1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="unordered_list">
        <li>This is an unordered list.</li>
        <li>All items in this list should have a yellow background.</li>
        <li>Just the items though - not the whole list!</li>
    </ul>

    <ol id="ordered_list">
        <li>This is an ordered list.</li>
        <li>All items in this list should have a teal background.</li>
        <li>Just the items thought - not the whole list!</li>
    </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
#unordered_list {
background-color: yellow;
}

#ordered_list li{
background-color: rgb(2, 132, 130);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want... I see you achieved something in there...

Comment: add `li` to `#unordered_list` like the one below `#ordered_list li`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h3p7v70j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `padding` on the `ul` element.

```
#unordered_list {
     padding-left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/mevohrmp/1/